# .NET error and Server 2008

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008

We are currently running 2 servers, one that hosts an application called IFCA, which is an accounting software, and one that hosts its database. If I run the app as Administrator everything works fine, but not if I am a User. The error I get is

> Procedure or function ... has too many arguments specified

At first I thought it was a permission problem. I tried to give a User more and more permission until I finally made that user an Administrator and still I got that error.

So my question is besides permissions what else are the differences between Admin and non-Admin on Win Server 2008?

Thank you

Comment: It might be a permissions problem in the database instance, not on the OS.  If the application is accessing the database with an integrated security context then the two different users might have access to two different versions of a function or stored procedure.

Comment: How would I see how permissions in the DB is connected to Server's user level? I had thought that DB permission would depend on App's user level since the app has its own user system. Now that I think about it it makes sense to go all the way up to Server user level. Not sure where to look for this info. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: It all depends on how the users are set up and how the application is accessing the database.  The connection string that the application uses would be a good place to start to determine that.  How the DB's security connects to the OS's security is more of a question for the DBA (or for ServerFault).  You can probably attach a SQL Profiler to the DB to determine exactly what's being accessed when it fails (and maybe even see more useful info about the failure).  Then try to re-create that manually against the DB with the same user context, removing the application from the equation.

Comment: @David I did a bit of digging and found a file that describes the app's settings. It looks like every app user connects to the DB using the same login and password regardless of his Server user level. Any other ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the application is calling different function when running in administrator context and the failing function when run in User. 
Check if the application has any logs (.log files, logs in event logs, etc) to get more details about the error.

Comment: Did not see anything related to the app in Event viewer. Then again, I may have missed it cause I don't know what to look for... I'll have to check with the devs about the app logs. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: haven't got an answer from devs about logs. Any other ideas where I can look for some kind of history?